# input[type = "file"], different mime types in different OS and browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-upload

While uploading csv file on chrome I do not get any type( on uploading other file like .pdf, .jpg etc., I got their type). This problem occur only in Window's chrome browser. In other browser and OS it works fine. I am using latest chrome version and example code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body onload="myFunction()">
       <input type="file" id="myFile" onchange="myFunction()">
       <p id="demo"></p>
     
       <script>
           function myFunction(){
               var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
               var type = x.files[0].type;
               
               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'TYPE : '+type;
           }
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My Plunker Example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5T7ZB7yQ10pyHw5ctic?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible MIME types for CSV files, depending on the user's OS and browser version. So you need to create an array of possible mime types and check the file type against it.

Possible array:

```
var mimes = ['text/csv',
    'text/plain',
    'application/csv',
    'text/comma-separated-values',
    'application/excel',
    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'application/vnd.msexcel',
    'text/anytext',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/txt']
```

Comment: Thanks for answer #SuperHornet.

But These mime type are use for validating the file type format but, I don't get file type. it gives me empty string. please se the plunker example above.

Comment: I just tested your code in Chrome Win7 it's not empty and returns 'application/vnd.ms-excel' @Abhishek

Comment: Are you tested the .csv file?
The problem is for .csv format

Comment: @Abhishek, yes I did.

Comment: ok Thanks, i think this problem occurs in my PC, it doesn't show file type when i uploaded .csv file